# If $\deg^+(u) = \deg^+(v)$ for all vertices in a simple digraph, then $\deg^-(u) = \deg^-(v)$ for all vertices. Is this a counterexample?

Tags: graph-theory

I was asked to prove the following statement:

> If $\deg^+(u) = \deg^+(v)$ for all vertices in a simple digraph, then
> $\deg^-(u) = \deg^-(v)$ for all vertices.

Where $\deg^+(u)$ is the number of vertices $v$ such that there is an edge from $u$ to $v$.

I have been drawing some graphs to figure out how I can prove that and I stumbled upon the following graph:

[image]

As you can see there is two outgoing edges from all nodes so $\deg^+(u) = \deg^+(v)$ for all vertices but $\deg^-(a) = 0$ while $\deg^-(d) = 2$. Is the statement true and my graph wrong or is the statement wrong?

Comment: Can you define a "simple digraph"?

Comment: As defined here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleDirectedGraph.html it is a directed graph with no loops and no parallel edges going in the same direction.

Comment: Great. Is your example a simple digraph?

Comment: As far as I can see it is. It is 1) a directed graph, 2) has no edges from a node to itself, 3) does not have parallel edges going in the same direction. Am I misunderstanding the definition such that the edge $bc$ is invalid because there is an edge $cb$?

Comment: No, that's valid. As far as I know, this is indeed a simple digraph, unless I'm overlooking something myself.

Comment: Right, it's a valid simple digraph, and so you have a counterexample to the statement. I was trying to get you to evaluate the "is my graph wrong" part of your question.

Comment: Well... I triple checked to make sure I did not mistranslate or mistyped the statement but it sure does seem like I have found a counterexample. Thank you all.

Comment: The statement is wrong. In fact you can construct an oriented graph (two vertices are joined by at most one edge in one direction) with the discrepancy arbitrarily large. E.g., take three vertices $a,b,c$ with arcs $ab,bc,ca$ and addivional vertices $x_i$ ($1\le i\le N$) with arcs $x_ia$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is not true, as shown your by counterexample.

---

There is a simpler counterexample:
$ a \rightarrow b $
$ b \rightarrow c $
$ c \rightarrow b$
Writing it this way, you can see that conditioning what happens on the LHS (the number of times each vertex appears) doesn't give us much restriction on the RHS. As such, it's unlikely that the statement is true (unless something much deeper happens).